# Validate Data that has been posted to Google AppEngine DataStore

Tags: json, google-app-engine, validation, cron, datastore

I am working with an Arduino project that uses Google AppEngine to post data that it collects from various sensors.  To give you an idea, here is a link to the project:  http://www.iowa-aquaponics.com

I am finding that occasionally the Arduino will post, or goggle app engine receives, data that isn't valid.

This would be a good entry:
http://www.mysite.appspot.com/adacs/arduino?&Temp=80.6&Humidity=82.2&AmbientLDR=16&WaterTemp=79.3&pHValue=5.03&doValue=2.5

Occasionally, a character will drop and i will either get a decimal point that is missing or it will drop an & and what should be a number value like 80.6 turns into a sting like 80.6umidity.

Since the Google AppEngine is seeing this as a string, it goes in the datastore no problem.  When I query this data into a JSON table, it will fail because it is looking for a number and it is getting a string.

I was thinking of writing a CRON job that would run each time a new data set was submitted and it would validate the data and delete the record if any of the elements were not valid.  I am collecting data every 10 minutes or so, so I am fine with occasionally dropping some records.  I would rather have this over not being able to see any data because one element of the JSON table is not valid.

I am curious of some other ideas to handle this situation.  If there is a best practice for this, please let me know.  Thanks everyone.

Comment: Need to see how you are decoding your json data.  I would have thought '80.6umidity.' would be two different values in the json structure, so that you would in fact get 80.6 and umidity  .  You probably need to supply us with the inbound structure and how you are parsing it to get any help.

Comment: I will post the data string when I get my next bad input.  I have been going out there and deleting the row so that the page will display...i have been getting a few a day, so it shouldn't take long.  Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Even a valid data packet, and json structure will do.  Is the json being created directly on the arduino  and submitted from it?

Comment: I deleted the table and waited for a poll so there isn't so much data and so you can see what a successful string looks like...

[{'DO': 2.5, 'MinWTemp': 72.0, 'MaxHumidity': 90.0, 'MaxTemp': 85.0, 'MaxDO': 2.0, 'Temp': 82.200000000000003, 'MaxWTemp': 80.0, 'MinLight': 200.0, 'MinTemp': 75.0, 'MaxPH': 7.5, 'MaxLight': 800.0, 'Humidity': 74.0, 'MinHumidity': 60.0, 'MinDO': 1.5, 'Time': u'23:56:42', 'WTemp': 78.799999999999997, 'MinPH': 6.5, 'Light': 1.0, 'PH': 4.7699999999999996}]

Comment: OK, here we go...the Arduino posted this:
/adacs/arduino?&Temp=82.6&Humidity=73.4&AmbientLDR=11&WaterTemp=78.8&pHValue=5.17&doValue=2.5
Google AppEngine recieved this:
/adacs/arduino?&Temp=82.6Humidity=73.4&AmbientLDR=11&WaterTemp=78.8&pHValue=5.17&doValue=2.5
With no & in front of Humidity, that causes an issue.

If I look under the Data Viewer, the Temp entry for that row reads:  82.6Humidity=73.4

Comment: For the URL to be incomplete on googles side I suspect the arduino code may not be 100%.  I would look at the URL sent over the wire at your end to know that the data on the wire is correct.  If any one was having problems with in transit URL's with appengine then there would be a huge noise about it.

Comment: Great point Tim.  I will get a trace and see what is being transmitted.  I am seeing some disconnects, so it really could be a connectivity issue on the Arduino side.